# How did my variable turn into a function?

Tags: python, function, variables, calling-convention

Hello fellow S Overflowers. This question might seem dumb to some, but I cannot express how much asking these conceptual questions has helped me understand coding in general and for that I want to preface the question saying I appreciate all of you very much!!

My doubt here is: How did the variable `Twice` at the end, turned into a function call to which I could put parentheses on. How could a variable start behaving as a function?

Apologies if this is obvious to some, but I'd love some human explaining because being new to the scene, documentation jargon gets pretty complicated.

```
#Define echo
def echo(n):
    """Return the inner_echo function."""

    # Define inner_echo
    def inner_echo(word1):
        """Concatenate n copies of word1."""
        echo_word = word1 * n
        return echo_word

    # Return inner_echo
    return(inner_echo)

#Call echo: twice        
twice = echo(2)
    
#Call twice() and print
print(twice('hello'))
```

Comment: Your variable always held a reference to a function. It didn't 'become' anything. do print(type(echo)) after twice=echo(2). You will see, it is a function. Functions are first class citizens in Python so a variable can point to a function.

Comment: Your messages are very kind, but it's not the convention we have for asking questions on SO. You need to just ask your question. That way we can see what your question is quickly and determine whether or not we can help and move on if we can't without needing to read through things first to arrive at the question. Drop the first and last paragraph of your question. Only the second paragraph is actually question.

Comment: `inner_echo` is a a function. `echo` returns `inner_echo`. So when you assign the result of `echo(2)` to a variable, that variable now holds a function.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for that! If I may take it further, why does calling echo(2) on its own returns this:
 ' <function __main__.echo.<locals>.inner_echo(word1)> '

Comment: What do you think it should return instead? That's what a nested function looks like.

Comment: Is there a way to skip assigning twice = echo(2) and twice('hello') in order to get the same result? @Barmar

Comment: `print(echo(2)('hello'))`

Comment: Beautiful! Could you explain why? does putting () after the initial function call, works with the nested function? Is the reason just because of syntax?

Comment: You have a function that returns a function. The first set of parens call the outer function, the second set calls the function that the outer function returned.

Answer (score 0):

In the `echo` function, you are returning `inner_echo`, which is pointer to a function, not its return value. In order to return the output of `inner_echo` you need to call it.

```
...
    # Return inner_echo value
    return(inner_echo(word))
...
```

You returned the nested function object, so `twice` becomes function object of `inner_echo` encapsulated in the enviroment from which it was returned. It means python saves the `n` variable, which does not exist inside `inner_echo` and twice becomes `inner_echo` function with given n value (2 in your example).

This would be unsafe code in other languages, which don't save the eviroment variables, however python does this implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

In Python variables can hold numbers, strings, functions, objects, even modules. You can put just about anything in a variable.

When you do `return(inner_echo)`, `inner_echo` is a function. That's how you ended up with a function. If you did `return(inner_echo(word1))`, then the variable `twice` would end up containing 'hellohello' which might be more in line with what you're expecting.